# Why are PHP string functions not multi-byte safe by default?

Tags: php, encoding, multibyte

Why are the PHP multi-byte string functions (the ones which start with `mb_`) not used by default in PHP?

Comment: The double-negative way of asking is a little unusual.

Comment: Compatibility! (The answer to 99% of "why isn't this better thing the default?" questions.)

Comment: Compatibility ***and*** shitty design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backwards compatibility.  Old PHP scripts depend on non-multibyte functionality.

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Answer (score 0):

Because non-multibyte functions were there first.